# красные пиксели в тексте

Tags: html, css

[image: test]

Здравствуйте, уже неделю бьюсь с проблемой и не знаю как её решить, первая строчка текст с нужным цветом на другом сайте, вторая строчка текст с этим же цветом но на моем сайте, нивкакую текст не хочет становится бирюзовым цветом, только темно синим, а все из за этих идиотских красных пикселей (тестил на хроме) , я уже не знаю что делать и как сделать нужный мне цвет

Comment: Нужно смотреть в сторону CSS и сглаживания.

Comment: сделай шрифт больше или вообще поменяй его

Comment: Может Вы покажете свой html / css ?